# SQL Regex throwing state=42000,code=40000

Tags: sql, regex, case, hiveql

```
case regexp_extract(network_information,'^([\\w|-]+)[.|;].*',1) then .........
```

For this part of code I am getting **ParseException line 22:2 cannot recognize input near '*' ',' 'case' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)**
Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp` looks good. case is wrong. It should be like this:

```
case when regexp_extract(network_information,'^([\\w|-]+)[.|;].*',1) = 'something'
         then ...
 end
```

Or like this:

```
case regexp_extract(network_information,'^([\\w|-]+)[.|;].*',1)
     when 'something'      then ...
     when 'something-else' then ...
 end
```